# ternary operator IF else Java

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

Want to check why is it throwing error when i'm trying to concat a string with a ternary operator if else inside?

E.g

```
String varA = null;
String concatString = "something1" + "something2" + varA == null?"":varA.toUpperCase();
```

but when i'm trying to do this and it work:

```
String varA = null;
varA = varA == null?"":varA.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis in this case to force the order of evaluation; something like

```
String concatString = "something1" + "something2"
        + (varA == null ? "" : varA.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by force the order of evaluation?

Comment: [JLS-15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) says (in part) *The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators `&&`, `||`, and **`? :`**) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.*